# Getting the current chat room ID

Tags: javascript, beginner, jquery, node.js, socket

I need `roomId` (an `auto_increment` primary key) to locate a specific room to update chat info. My way of doing it right now is dumb.

In `createRoom.js`, I use `roomName` from a form that a user has entered to create a room model and find its `roomId`, then make `roomId` a param of a URL:

```
var Room = require('../models/database').Room

exports.create = function (req, res) {


Room
    .create({
        room_name: req.body.roomName
    })
    .complete(function () {

        Room
            .find({where: {room_name: req.body.roomName}})
            .success(function (room) {


                res.redirect('rooms/videochat/' + req.body.roomName + '/' + room.room_id);


        })

    })

};
```

in `routes.js`, I grab `roomId` with `req.params.roomId` and pass it to a view file jade so it can be displayed on a video chat page:

```
app.get('/rooms/videochat/:roomName/:roomId', function (req, res) {
    res.render('videochat.jade', {roomName: req.params.roomName, roomId: req.params.roomId});
});
```

In the client side JavaScript, I use

```
var roomId = $('#roomId span').text();
```

to get the `roomId`, then use socket.emit to pass it back to server side:

```
socket.emit('updateStartTime', roomId);
```

Comment: It seems like your code does not work as it will not fire `socket.on('disconnect')`, which makes it off-topic for CR.

Comment: Hi, it will fire when users click close window button.

Comment: @konijn the code works as it can get roomId successfully. i just want to see if there is a bette way. it does not contain broken code

Comment: Voting to re-open now

Comment: you have a lot of Empty White Space in that code,  you should really get rid of that in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question,

my first point is that it is not clear how you wrote the `Room` module, but ideally, that module should do 2 things:

1. Provide the created room to `complete`
2. Provide a way to deal with failure

Then, I would expect in the top code to see something like this:

```
var Room = require('../models/database').Room

exports.create = function (req, res) {
    Room.create({
        room_name: req.body.roomName
    })
    .complete(function ( success, room ) {
        if( success )
            res.redirect('rooms/videochat/' + room.roomName + '/' + room.roomId );
        else
            res.redirect('cuteapologetickittenvideo/');
    });
};
```

You will notice that I also changed `req.body.roomName` -> room.room_name -> room.roomName which makes more sense to me. On a general note I find it bad practice to require `room_name` in your call to the constructor, but `roomName` in the request. I would suggest to stick to 1 convention (The JavaScript One) and use `roomName` everywhere. Then you could write

```
var Room = require('../models/database').Room

exports.create = function (req, res) {
    Room.create( req.body ).complete(function roomComplete( success, room ) {
        if( success )
            res.redirect('rooms/videochat/' + room.roomName + '/' + room.roomId );
        else
            res.redirect('cuteapologetickittenvideo/');
    });
};
```

For the Jade processing, you should be able to get room id and name from the matching on `'/rooms/videochat/:roomName/:roomId'`.

Same for the client side javascript, I would be more inclined to get this from the URL than from a field in the HTML.